# How can I know when LASTMOVE in IIB will return true or false?

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

```
-- Shared row variable for caching config data. Declared at Global scope.
DECLARE S_ConfigSharedRow SHARED ROW;

CREATE COMPUTE MODULE TheFirstComputeNode
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    CFGDATA_CACHE_LOCK: BEGIN ATOMIC
        -- If the configuration data is not available in the cache then load it from the CONFIG table
        DECLARE CfgDataRef REFERENCE TO S_ConfigSharedRow.CfgDataCache;
        IF NOT LASTMOVE(CfgDataRef) THEN
            -- Select all the relevant content from the actual database in one go.
            DECLARE DBResults ROW;
            DECLARE RetryCount INTEGER 5;
            SET DBResults.Row[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT * FROM CONFIG');

            -- Typically you would post process the content from the DB into a more amenable 
            -- structure but the following will get the data into the shared variable
            CREATE LASTCHILD OF S_ConfigSharedRow.CfgDataCache FROM DBResults;
        END IF;
    END CFGDATA_CACHE_LOCK;

    -- Config data is now available for use

    RETURN TRUE;
END;
END MODULE;
```

Hi guys, can I ask which is the scenario that LASTMOVE in this case return true, and which case is false. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with [LASTMOVE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=functions-lastmove-function) is that it can return `NULL`, so better only check for `TRUE`:

```
    DECLARE CfgDataRef REFERENCE TO S_ConfigSharedRow.CfgDataCache;
    IF LASTMOVE(CfgDataRef) THEN
        -- Nothing to do
    ELSE
        -- Select all the relevant content ...
    END IF;
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for your answer @Daniel. But the thing here is I don't know when it will be true? Please can you explain that point?

Comment: This answer provides a link to the IBM documentation for LASTMOVE. Please explain what information you need - I think the IBM docs describe the behaviour quite well.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen the document many times. The LASTMOVE in the document always go with MOVE and in the while loop, but in this case it just go alone and not even in the while loop, so I just got some confusing how does it work? Because my task is migration this code into another language name Mulesoft 4, and I'm not even an expert or a developer in this esql language at all. That's why I need to understand it more if I want to migrate it.

Comment: The `REFERENCE TO` acts as a `MOVE`, this is why the following `LASTMOVE` works, see also the first example in [Creating dynamic field references](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=content-creating-dynamic-field-references).